# zend auto loader... custom classes.  How do I get it to work?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-autoloader

I am looking to create my own collection of class files in the library/common folder

```
/library/common/*class files go in here*
```

Inside the folder I will have various class files that I want to make available

such as

```
DecoratorSimple.php
```

example of the code can be seen below?

```
class Common_Decorator_SimpleInput extends Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract
{
  // code goes in here
}
```

The question I have is how do I get the zend application to automatically load anything in common folder that has the the prefix of Common_

I have tried adding the following to the bootstrap but it did not work

```
protected function _initTestAutoLoader(){

    $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $autoloader->registerNamespace('Common_');

    // try and load the class
    $testVar = new Common_Decorator_SimpleInput();
    var_dump($test);
}
```

Comment: What's the error that you get? Also, I think the problem is because you didn't register /Library/ in  `include_path`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your class name matching the library path...
eg Common_Decorator_SimpleInput
must be in /library/Common/Decorator/SimpleInput.php

Comment: this is what it was.  For every "_" (seperator) i needed to add an extra folder.